# how to separate the whole number and decimal numbers in a separate columns using python csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, floating-point

I saw many similar questions like this but none have been done in csv file using python. Basically I have a column with a decimal numbers and I want to write a code where it creates 2 new columns one for just whole number and other for decimals. I turned the column into numeric using the code below.

```
df['hour_num'] = pd.to_numeric(df['total_time'])
```

I already have the column 'total_time' and 'hour_num'. I want to know how to get the column 'Whole number' and 'Decimal'

here is the pic to help better understand.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeunN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the numbers to strings and split on `.`, convert to a DataFrame and assign to original DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[2.123, 3.557, 0.123456]})
df[['whole number', 'decimal']] = df['col1'].astype(str).str.split('.').apply(pd.Series)
df['decimal'] = ('0.' + df['decimal']).astype(float)
df['whole number'] = df['whole number'].astype(int)
```

Output:

```
       col1  whole number   decimal
0  2.123000             2  0.123000
1  3.557000             3  0.557000
2  0.123456             0  0.123456
```